# Stripe Proration - Annual Billing, Changes in Quantity Charged Monthly

Tags: stripe-payments

Looking to understand the best way to manage a SaaS app subscription model in stripe with annual plans available.

High Level - the app has organisations and users - the stripe customer is set up against the organisation ('Team Billing').

At the moment, I have a function set up whereby a change in the number of active users in the organisation changes the quantity on the stripe organisation, i.e.:

```
const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve(subscription_id);
await stripe.subscriptions.update(subscription_id, {
  items: [{
    id: subscription.items.data[0].id,
    quantity: new_user_count,
  }],
});
```

However for customers on an annual plan, this is delayed until the end of their billing cycle which could be up to a year, which is obviously not ideal.

I considered setting the `proration_behaviour` to `always_invoice` but the issue with this is it will immediately send an invoice, which may not be ideal for many customers (especially if they add/remove users often).

I then considered setting the `proration_date` to the end of the month for example, but then lose out on the prorated charge during the month.

Ideally, I'm looking for a way to have the quantities updated immediately (even daily is fine), and then if a user on an annual plan increases/decreases users during the month, an invoice would be issued at the end of the month with the difference in cost.

Is this something obvious I am missing, or is there a way to easily achieve this?

Comment: The only way I can think is to manually call the API yourself each month to create an invoice(which will suck in any outstanding proration from the previous updates you made) unfortunately.